# Detect EOF between two images transmitted by bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, camera

Im using Bluetooth to transfer image from Android camera.callback to PC. on windows side i use DataInputStream to read the incoming data. the problem is that the PC side cannot detect the end of first image and second image. hence i cannot reconstruct the image.

the error of DataoutputStream is in following code

```
    public void create_file() {
    synchronized (frames) {
        if (frames.size() > 0) {
            Log.i("dhiraj", "" + frames.size());
            YuvImage image = new YuvImage(frames.remove(0),
                    ImageFormat.NV21, size.width, size.height, null);

            try {
                out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.i("dhiraj", "new outstream error");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("dhiraj", "new outstream");
            image.compressToJpeg(rectangle, 90, baos);
            Log.i("dhiraj", "compressed");
            try {                   
                out.write(baos.toByteArray());
                Log.i("dhiraj", "" + baos.size());
                Log.i("dhiraj", "output");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("dhiraj", "IO");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("dhiraj", "new outstream close error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible to send the size before each image? So you can just read for n bytes.
Perhaps write the size to a file.

Pseudo:

```
for (each image)
    write (size of image) to size.txt on Android
    transfer size.txt to PC
    read the (size of image) from size.txt 
    read for (size of image) from bluetooth
end for
```

Another option is to append a very unique sequence of characters to the end of each image, and strip it off after reception.
If this isn't unique enough you run the chance of finding that sequence somewhere in the image and chopping an image in pieces.

Comment: i might work but it will considerably slow down the entire operation. i want to send the images very fast so that they can be projected and we get a view as if a video is played... else i want to stream camera preview to pc using bluetooth

Comment: "considerably slow down the entire operation"?? Sending a file with a few characters in it... or even better yet just an integer as a bytestream... is only a few bytes.

There's really only two options: 1) A termination character (or sequence). 2) Attach a header with the size to know how much to read. (instead of adding a header to the images you could just send the size as a seperate xfer, to simplify things).

Comment: Have you checked that the image format you're sending doesn't already have a termination sequence / character? Open a few images in a hex editor and see if you can recognize any patterns that they all have in common at the end.

Comment: ya they all have FF D9 as the terminating character... :( still no luck !

Comment: when i close the DataOutputStream at android side the image gets reconstructed properly, so i tried to close it afer every write and create it again in a loop, but it gives me error. Logcat reads java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad to hear it.
Perhaps accept an answer so that this issue might RIP.

Comment: Thanks braden a lot. I have yet another question. I have asked  but didn't get any reply . Is it possible to get video stream from camera to send over Bluetooth ?

Comment: I found your other question and answered it.

Comment: Finally i had to restore to using only Images and sending over Bluetooth and it worked marvellously, even integrating with SKYPE... :)

Comment: oh great, congratulations. is it on the market? if so what's the name?